# has_and_belongs_to_many allows no duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following 2 models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :uniq => false
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :orders, :uniq => false
end
```

they are joined by a reference table `orders_products`

i want order to be able to contain more that 1 instance of same product, so when i `@order.product_ids = [2,2,2]`, which means add 3 times product with id 2

that results in `@order.product_ids = [2]`, is there anyway to tell Model that i do want duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend (neither think of any use) the way you are trying to implement the association here. Although there is a many-many relation between the 2 models, what you are trying to do is drawing 3 lines from point 1 to point 2. If you try to use `@order.product_ids = [2,3,4]` instead, it should work fine and make sense.
In your case, where you want multiple products in an order, you should have some an extra column on the relationship table `orders_products` that represents the number of `Product` per `Order`. In such cases, `has_many` is recommended over `habtm` association because you have more control over the relationship table. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Just to repeat and clarify the above, the proper choice here is a full fledged join model, not HABTM.  Typically in the use case in the question, this is usually called a "line item" which is associated with an order and a product, and includes a "count" field.

Comment: Right, or OrderItem, ie an Order has_many :order_items, and an OrderItem has_one :product along with a quantity.